# Ec2TagFilters in deployment group for ComputePlatform: Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to work my way through a Cloud Formation stack creation.  The stack includes an `AWS::CodeDeploy::Application` using `CodePlatform: Lambda`.  It also has an `AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup`.

If I run create-stack *without* the deployment group present, everything seems to work.  I can then go into the web UI, and add the deployment group by hand.

But if I describe the deployment group in the template, and run `create-stack`, the  create of the deployment group fails, and the stack gets rolled back.  The error message looks like:

> For Lambda deployment group, ec2TagFilters can not be specified (Service: AmazonCodeDeploy; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidEC2TagException; Request ID: c4347652-c755-11e8-b8f1-6f54b77ae7fe)

... but my template's description of the deployment group doesn't include `Ec2TagFilters`

Comment: Share your CFT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into the same thing.  No reference to the parameter, still errors.  Added a Null Ec2TagFilters parameter and no luck.  Weirdly, I then added a Deployment Style parameter, tried again, and it succeeded.  Here's the CFN I ended with:

```
TestSSHConnectivityCodeDeployGroup:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Condition: InPrimaryRegion
    Properties:
        ApplicationName: !Ref TestSSHConnectivityCodeDeployApplication
        DeploymentGroupName: Lambda-TestSSHConnectivity
        DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce
        DeploymentStyle:
            DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
            DeploymentType: BLUE_GREEN
        ServiceRoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/AWS-CodeDeploy-Service
```

Comment: To clarify for others you have to WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL and BLUE_GREEN for Lamba Deployment Style. You cannot use IN_PLACE or WITHOUT_TRAFFIC_CONTROL

Comment: This work around cannot be applied if you need to specify Development. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error happening in only 1 of my stacks in us-west-2.  It was only a gamma environment so I deleted the stack, re-created it and everything was fine.

That won't work for everyone, but it did work in my case.