# CloudFormation fails to create CodeDeploy DeploymentGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to put together some CloudFormation to setup CodePipeline to deploy from Github to ECS/Fargate.

However, I consistently get the error:

```
For ECS deployment group, ec2TagFilters can not be specified (Service: AmazonCodeDeploy; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidEC2TagException;
```

Whenever I try to stand up my CloudFormation stack. However, I don't have 'ec2TagFilters' in my file at all.

The only reference I can find to this issue is an older [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636182/ec2tagfilters-in-deployment-group-for-computeplatform-lambda) but they are targeting Lambda and the 'fix' suggested didn't work for me.

The relevant snippet of CF YAML:

```
    ExampleApp:
      Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
      Properties:
        ApplicationName: !Join [ "-", [ "example", !Ref "Environment" ] ]
        ComputePlatform: ECS

    ExampleDeploymentGroup:
      Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
      Properties:
        ApplicationName: !Ref ExampleApp
        DeploymentGroupName: !Join [ "-", [ "example", !Ref "Environment"] ]
        ServiceRoleArn: !Ref ServiceRoleArn
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Also having same issue. Have you managed to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this to work. However, I realised I don't need an Application/DeploymentGroup for my setup.

CodeDeploy can use 'ECS' as a Provider in the Deploy step which removes the necessity.

CF for anyone who ends up here:

```
- Name: Deploy
  Actions:
    - Name: Deploy
      RunOrder: 2
      InputArtifacts:
        - Name: AppBuilt
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Deploy
        Owner: AWS
        Version: 1
        Provider: ECS
      Configuration:
        ClusterName: !Ref EcsCluster
        ServiceName: !Ref EcsService
```

Answer (score 0):

From AWS Documentation:

> *ECS blue/green deployments through CodeDeploy do not use the AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup resource.*

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codedeploy-deploymentgroup.html